# android app does not respond after start service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

i want to creat android service which will check if there is new items in my website using json :) 
so my first step is to Test if service will be good :) 
i created my service like that

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    public static boolean ServiceIsRun=false;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int i = 1;

        while (ServiceIsRun){
            i++;
            Log.i("broadService","hello from Service"+i);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

and my receiver :

```
public class NotifyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.latestBabiaNews")){
            Log.i("broadReceiver","hello from Broadcast");
        }

    }
}
```

ps : i have asynctask in my fragmenet , to load data from server , 
and i called the service  like that ( in onPostExecute()

```
 if(NotifyService.ServiceIsRun==false){
                NotifyService.ServiceIsRun=true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),NotifyService.class);
                getActivity().startService(intent);
            }
```

..
my xml manifest :

```
 <service
        android:name=".NotifyService">

    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".NotifyBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.latestBabiaNews">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
```

### so the result my app started , also the service , but the app crash and still not respond , and on android studio consol i still show the service running ( with Log message )

also when i use IntentService , it work good for me , but with Service it does not ? is it problem with multiThreading or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Services run in the same thread with the rest of your application. If you block in the service, you block the entire application.

If you want to do something that blocks, start a new thread in your server. Just make sure you do it correctly (for instance, `onStartCommand` maybe called multiple times during the lifetime of you service).

Alternatively you could set it up so that your service does everything asynchronously and doesn't block. Whether that's easier or not depends on what the service eventually does.